# How store a JSON in a QR code using Angular

Tags: angular, angular6, qr-code

I'm generating `QR codes` from my Angular web app. I'm using the `npm` package **ngx-qrcode2** to generate the QR code.

Is there a way with this `npm` package or another npm package to store a `JSON` object in the QR. Then read QR,and extract the JSON using the qr reader **zxing/ngx-scanner**.

Currently, I'm able to achieve this if I convert the JSON to a string, store that string in the QR and then when I read it, a parse it back to a `JSON`.

This is what I have done so far.

**TO GENERATE THE QR CODE**
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ja13vl

**TO READ THE QR CODE**
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qr-reader

Comment: "I'm able to achieve this if I convert the JSON to a string". Does that not solve your question?

Comment: @molamk yes, you are right my friend. I just felt it was a little hackie. This is my first time working with QRs and I didn't know If what I did was the correct or best way to do it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You seem to have found the solution and it seems totally right I think.

> Currently I'm able to achieve this if I convert the JSON to a string

As you say, if you want to store raw JSON in the QR code, you have to stringify it first using `JSON.stringify(json)`.
When reading the QR code, you have no choice but to parse the string to get the raw JSON back, using `JSON.parse(str)`.

But, you could also **compress** the JSON and store a string representing this compressed JSON instead. This will allow you to store more information in the QR code.

You can use a library like [`jsonpack`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonpack) for this, which compresses up to 55% of the original size. You can use it like this:

```
const qrcode = jsonpack.pack(json);
const json = jsonpack.unpack(qrcode);
```

You can find more compression ideas for QR codes [on this page](https://bountify.co/javascript-json-to-most-compact-qr-code).

Comment: Thanks so much for you answer. It was my first time working with QRs so I didn't know if what I did was correct. Very useful information know that I can even compress a JSON!!! that's awesome. Thanks so much

Comment: @Patricio Vargas, I am happy it helped! Please consider marking the answer accepted if you think it is appropriate!